# Error in XAF: Requires a single object selected

Tags: xaf

I'm using XAF to create some applications.
I have a problem with this scenario:

1. In some ViewController I'm creating a new object (not saving it) and opening it in 
   edit mode.
2. After object is created using

`var newObject = ObjectSpace.CreateObject<MasterType>()`

I fill its details using:

```
newObject.Details = new List<Details>() {new Detail(), new Detail, new Detail()};
```

3. When the form opens in te web everything seems greate, **but** when I click one of detail items on the grid to open for edit, this error appears:

> Message:    An error with number 1007 has occurred. Error message:
>   Unable to execute disabled or inactive action ListViewShowObject.
>   Disable reasons: Requires a single object selected.

Comment: There seems to be no connection between steps 1 and 2 and the error 3. You can try to create a sample project that reproduces this problem and attach it on a ticket on DevExpress Support Center.

Comment: I think this was a bug and devexpress has resolved this bug: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T321864 check the link

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error. I saved the detail items when I created the original object in the controller. In my case the detail items are an aggregated association so if the user decides not to save the original object the detail items will be deleted.